# RKClient POST method and special caracters

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm facing an odd behavior. I use the following code to send an HTTP
request to a server using a POST method

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] post:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api"]
                           params:aDict
                         delegate:self];
```

The dictionary that hold the values is as followed :

```
NSDictionary *comment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray
arrayWithObjects:@"wallcomment", [self.wall
valueForKey:@"wallMessageId"], [self.textView text], nil]
                                                        forKeys:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a01call", @"a01wall_message_id",
@"a01comment", nil]];
```

When  [self.textView text] is filled in with French word with accent
the server receive with wrong encoding : "Test @ vérification
caractères spéciaux"

I do not manipulate the textview text before posting so encoding is also UTF8.

When i check the POST header, the content-type is not having the encoding type. I tried to add it with the following method but it's not added :

```
- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)header
```

Any special method or property i haven't seen in the documentation ?

I'm using the RestKit 0.9.3

Comment: This may be obvious, but you need to call *setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:* before you call *post*. If you do this correctly, then debug line 216 in RKClient.m to see where your headers are going.

Comment: I remember i tried to setHTTPHeader field to add UTF-8 encoding along with the Content-Type but when i check the header values content-type remains application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: The important piece of information here is **when** do you set the headers, before you call *post* or after? If before, and it's still not set, then debug line 216 as I said before.

Comment: Ok i'll give a try and check the line 216 to see what to could be the problem. Thanks

Comment: Is it correct, because still no UTF-8 ; [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] client] setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"api"
                                                      delegate:self
                                                         block:^(RKObjectLoader *loader)
     {
        ....
     }];

Comment: just to confirm i checked on RKClient line:216 the NSDictionary for additional HTTP header values is empty

Comment: So why exactly were you hiding the fact that you use RKObjectManager? Two important things now: 1. show me what you got in the loader configuration block. 2. RKObjectManager bypasses the RKClient entirely, it uses RKObjectLoader instead, which is a subclass of RKRequest, so technically you should never stop on line 216, unless you do something else that you didn't mention.

Comment: fair enough. But even doing so at the loader level still not working loader.additionalHTTPHeaders = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
                                                                    forKey:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: [[RKClient sharedClient] setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api"]
                           params:comment
                         delegate:self]; ==> {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
} WORKS. Now i have to find the same for [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath: /// Thank you for your help and sorry for the confusion

Comment: [[RKClient sharedClient] setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; If i check [[RKClient sharedClient] HTTPHeaders]; => It's OK but the trace shows different -> 
    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api"]
                           params:comment
                         delegate:self]; ==> HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}. HTTP Body: a01call=wallcomment&a01wall_message_id=182_3779&a01comment=Encore. // So still not taken into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"api" delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    [loader setAdditionalHTTPHeaders:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", @"Content-Type", nil]];
}];
```

Don't forget to add other headers if you need any.

One additional thing that I noticed while going through RestKit code, RKObjectManager line 222:

```
loader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
```

So don't be surprised you the method is GET, not POST. If you really need POST (which I think you don't), then change the method in the block.